# Unable to execute shell script with multiple command line options using paramiko ssh connection

Tags: python, linux, shell, python-2.7, ssh

I am able to successfully execute a shell script (which echoes only "Hello World" on a remote server through paramiko ssh connection using the following command:

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd /project/fcd_neptune/neptune_psv/fw;./new")

print stdout.readlines()
```

Output:
    [u'Hello World !\n']

But, for a huge shell script with different command line options I am unable to get ahead. This shell script (Do_Regr.sh) compiles several C files, generate builds, loads the image on a target CPU and runs several tests in regression. Is this the correct way to run this kind of shell script remotely from my Windows desktop? I am giving the following command:

```
stdin,stdout,stderr = ssh.exec_command("cd 
/project/fcd_neptune/neptune_psv/fw;./Do_Regr.sh -i Testlist_Regression.in -m 135.20.230.160 -g")
```

When I run the command from a shell after logging in to the Unix server, the tests run successfully. But while running through ssh.exec_command, there is an output folder generated with only one file which tells that it could not generate a build after compilation.

Comment: Try redirecting stdout/stdout of `Do_Regr.sh` to a file on the remote host to examine after your script finishes.

Comment: Your first example demonstrates that you can run shell commands which cd to a directory and run a script. If your second case is failing, it's probably due to something specific about what `Do_Regr.sh` is trying to do. We'd need to know what is in that script to be able to help.